# Finding the maximum sum from the subset sum using recursion

Tags: c++, c, recursion, subset

I want to print only the maximum sum from the subset sum. What I want actually is to compare all the subset sum values in the function and then return only the maximum sum in the main function.

What I tried to do was to save the subset sum values in a new array. Then compare the values in there. But I couldn't manage to do that as it returns nothing.
 I want suppose input `array` size is `n = 5`, *number of elements to sum* is `r = 3` And array is :

```
{1,2,3,4,5}
```

Then maximum sum should be `3 + 4 + 5 = 12`. But my code returns all the sum.

I want to save the sum values in the newArray

```
newArray[] = sum;
```

then find the maximum values from the newArray.

This is my `code` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void combinationRecursion(int start, int end, int index, int r, int *arr, int *data, int sum){

if(r == index){
    for(int i=0; i<r; i++){
        int val = data[i];
        cout<<val<<' ';
        sum = sum + data[i];

    }
    printf("sum %d\n",sum);
    printf("\n");

}
for(int i=start; i<end; i++){
    data[index] = arr[i];
    combinationRecursion(i+1, end, index+1, r, arr, data, sum);
   }
 }

 int main() {
     int arr[100], n, data[100], r;
     scanf("%d%d",&n,&r);

for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}
combinationRecursion(0, n, 0, r, arr, data, 0);
}
```

Comment: And the subset must be contiguous in the original set?

Comment: @Surt yes, subset must be contiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I've been able to solve this by setting max globally.
this's the modified version

```
int max1 = 0;
int combinationRecursion(int start, int end, int index, int r, int *arr, int *data){

if(r == index){
        int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<r; i++){
        int val = data[i];
        sum = sum + data[i];
    }
     if(max1<sum){
        max1 = sum;
   }

}
for(int i=start; i<end; i++){
    data[index] = arr[i];
    combinationRecursion(i+1, end, index+1, r, arr, data);
}
 return max1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the *subset* of size `k` out of set with cardinality `n` then you don't need to do any of the combination generation stuff. You can just sort the array in **decreasing order** and pick the top `k` elements, as they are sorted in decreasing order they will give the maximum sum of subset of size `k`.

Comment: yah i can do that. But what i want actually is to compare all the subset sum values in the recursive function and then return the maximum value in the main function so that I can use that value for another purpose

Comment: Hmm, why can't you use the value in this way? It seems the same to me.

Comment: @MavishA it doesnt matter how you compute the value ;) NiVeRs approach is valid, so even if you also need the other subset sums, you can use this approach to calculate the maximum....

Comment: @MavishA ... but if you already have all the subset sums, then finding the maximum value amongst them should actually be easier

Comment: @user463035818  yah, but I've not found any good way to store the subset sum. If you look at my code, you can see i want to compare the "sum" values and then find the max from them

Comment: @MavishA remove the C tag and use a `std::vector` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let see if we can do it using std::algorithms (untested code).

```
std::partial_sum(data.begin(), data.end(), std::plus<int>);
std::vector<int> subSetSum;
subSetSum.reserve(data.size()); // -3 but meh.
std::transform(data.begin(), data.begin()+subSetLength-1, std::back_inserter(subSetSum), std::minus<int>); // will be negative
auto maxSum = -std::min_element(subSetSum.begin(), subSetSum.end());
```

But there is no recursion here ...